# How to Convert Base64String to Byte[]

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to use AES encryption with encryption in one program and decryption in another. I have working code that encrypts the file but I need to extract the key to use in the other program to decrypt.

When I do this:

```
string key = String.Empty;
byte[] aesKey;
using (var aes = Aes.Create())
{
    aesKey = aes.Key;
    key = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
}
```

and use aesKey in my encrypt it works. When I try to convert from Base64 string to Byte[] it doesn't seem to work, It doesn't end up with the same bytes. How do you convert?

```
string sKey = "LvtZELDrB394hbSOi3SurLWAvC8adNpZiJmQDJHdfJU=";
aesKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sKey);
```

Comment: You use `Convert.FromBase64String`... always look for an inverse operation which actually *sounds* like it's the inverse. You're not wanting the UTF-8-encoded form of a string, so don't use `Encoding.UTF8`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a corresponding [`From` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.convert.frombase64string) that you should use.

```
byte[] aesKey = Convert.FromBase64String(sKey);
```